# Show a set is in the algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Assume $A_1, ... ,A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of a sample space $\Omega$. Set

\begin{align} B_i = A_i \setminus (A_1~ \cup~ ...~\cup~ A_{i-1}), i = 1,...,n.  \end{align} a) Only using the properties stated in our definition of an algebra, show that $B_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for $i = 1,...,n$.

b) Show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ = $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$.

I just can't see the steps involved with part a)... I realise inclusion-exclusion may be a way to go for part b), but I am not sure how that will work out explicitly...

Thanks for the help!

Sam

Comment: In your present definition all $B_{i}$'s are empty, so I suppose you want to exclude $A_i$ in the setminus.

Comment: Ah, typo! Sorry

Comment: The question is now as it was meant to be stated :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint to part $a)$
$$
B_i = A_i\setminus (A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_{i-1}) = A_i \cap (A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_{i-1})^c = A_i \cap A_{1}^{c}\cap\ldots\cap A_{i-1}^{c }.
$$

Comment: That's all I needed! I just couldn't see how to flip the set minus around... thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!